# Reskit response is just a string, not JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

In my app i am making different calls and they work except one call, that returns just a string in response as SUCCESS. I am getting this error

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'}
```

How can i tell the restkit to access the "Content-Type: text/plain"

This is a post call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. RestKit is designed to work with JSON objects only, and so it expects a JSON response (keeping with the RESTful paradigm).

However, you can definitely post objects using AFNetworking, which RestKit actually includes. I use AFNetworking for non-coreData-related correspondence. Here's a code sample on how to get the AFHTTPClient from RestKit and make a POST, expecting a `text/plain` response.

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient;
NSDictionary *requestObject = @{@"label1":data1, @"label2":data2};
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/plain"];
[httpClient postPath:urlPath parameters:requestObject success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *response = (NSString*)responseObject;
    if([response isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) NSLog(@"It worked!");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure code goes here
}];
```

If that's your only call expecting `text/plain`, change the `Accept` header back after you're done:

```
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

Comment: Not technically true. You can ask RestKit to process `text/plain` and you can deserialise that into something that can be mapped...

Comment: @Wain Oh, okay! Nice. I stand corrected then. Can you explain how or link to somewhere that explains how? I will happily delete my answer if you provide the correct one.

Comment: @Wain - I did some research but couldn't find it. Will be looking forward for your answer.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is completely wrong, using AFNetworking directly is a solution. You would create a class which implements `RKSerialization` protocol and submit it against the mime type then implement it to format the response in whatever way you choose.